# std::move a std::unique_ptr into stl containers. (MSVC compiler issue)

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-phone-8

There is a known bug with MSVC compiler where default move consturctors are not created.

The problem is I have a lot of classes that look similar to this:

```
struct User {
    std::string FirstName;
    std::string LastName;
    std::string Address;
    std::string PostalCode;
    std::string City;

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ProjectBase>> Projects;
};
```

How do I take a class like this and convert it into something that would work in this scenario:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<User>> users;
{
    // I use this logic often (create a temporary object and move it into stl container
    auto new_user=make_unique<User>();
    users.push_back(std::move(new_a));
}
users.back()->FirstName="Should";
users.back()->LastName="Work";

std::cout << "First Name: " <<  users.back()->FirstName << std::endl;
```

The above code DOES NOT work in Windows Phone 8 (because there is no move constructor) but works WORKS with a Visual Studio 2012 (v110) toolkit.

How would my User class look like if it had move constructors so it would work with Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Is there some reason you create a variable form `make_unique` instead of just doing `push_back(make_unique<User>())`?

Comment: Have you tried `User(User &&) = default;`?

Comment: @VaughnCato: MSVC does not support that yet.

Comment: Indeed one of the most important features missing. Who on earth needs things like variadic templates or constexpr if you cannot even define the simplest of types without a whole bunch of boilerplate? VS team, next time start with the low hanging fruit please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply call `std::move` to invoke the move constructor for each member:

```
User(User&& u)
  : FirstName(std::move(u.FirstName)),
    LastName(std::move(u.LastName)),
    Address(std::move(u.Address)),
    PostalCode(std::move(u.PostalCode)),
    City(std::move(u.City)),
    Projects(std::move(u.Projects))
{}
```

Also, to use `make_unique<User>();`, you will need a user-defined ctor also, i.e. `User(){}`.

Comment: I have over 50 classes with many levels of inheritance. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Grapes: The code you have shown requires a move ctor. Since the compiler does not generate one for you, you must explicitly define one. Otherwise, your only other choice is to avoid any code that requires a move ctor.

Comment: @Grapes It's tedious, but it will probably only take a few hours. Blame VS for not implicitly generating them like they are supposed to. It makes life very difficult. Note that if you add these, add move assignment operators as well.